Grease pencil strokes are visible in the viewport but disappear when rendered!
I've been trying to work this out for sometime now but it's still not working.
Z pass is turned on as well btw.
Any help would be appreciated


In the second screenshot, it's a bit small to read, but the render says something like "Remaining 2:51.15" and "Samples76/100". So the render is not finished yet - Grease Pencil is a post effect that will be added after rendering.
